# Excel VBA Autofilter contains with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I need to filter a range with multiple criteria with operator **Contains**

The following code works very well (2 critera):

```
shData.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("*a*", "*b*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But, not sure why the below code doesn't work (more than 2 criteria):

```
shData.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("*a*", "*b*", "*c*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a limitation of autofilters. You can't use more than two **contains** filters in the UI either.

You can either use an Advanced filter instead, or you can create an array of the values that match your criteria and filter using that:

```
Sub MultiContainsAutofilter()
    Dim vData
    Dim shData                As Worksheet
    Dim d                     As Object
    Dim i                     As Long

    Set shData = ActiveSheet
    vData = shData.UsedRange.Columns(2)

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
        If UCase$(vData(i, 1)) Like "*A*" Or UCase$(vData(i, 1)) Like "*B*" Or UCase$(vData(i, 1)) Like "*C*" Then
            d(vData(i, 1)) = Empty
        End If
    Next i

    If d.Count > 0 Then shData.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=d.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: I can iterate row by row, but it will be very slow

Comment: See my edited answer. It should be reasonably quick.

Comment: Please, What is the meaning of `d(vData(i, 1)) = Empty` ?

Comment: @Waleed it just adds an empty item to the dictionary.