# Autofilter exceptions with more than two criteria

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I'm trying to use my macro to filter my data, I want to allow everything except for three criteria.  My code works with two criteria but it won't allow me to add a third and I can't use the Criteria1:=Array function for some reason.  My code is:

```
wsO.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="<>Accept as Medicare product", Criteria2:="<>Accept as NJ Medicaid product", Criteria3:="<>Accept as Medicaid product", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Which returns a **name argument not found** (because I believe you can only add 2 criteria this way)

I have also tried:

```
wsO.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:=Array( _
"<>Accept as Medicare product", "<>Accept as NJ Medicaid product", "<>Accept as Medicaid product"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Which returns me an error of: **Run time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.**

Comment: I believe Array in filters only works on multiple matches rather than a set of "<>". You can get away with a helper column though

Comment: Two criteria is the max for exceptions. There is no way around this with the autofilter, with the exception of having your code loop through your list and create criteria for all of the ALLOWED values.

Comment: You could use an approach like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882661/excel-vba-autofilter-contains-with-multiple-criteria/32882806?noredirect=1#comment53597232_32882806 or use an advanced filter instead, or helper column with a formula.

Comment: You can use the Advanced Filter to do what you want. Additionally you can have the VBA hid the rows you do not want. Neither are difficult.

Comment: I don't know if this will work given what your other values may be in your list, but what using a fliter like `does not contain Medi` or `does not contain Accept as`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the range and hide the rows.

```
Sub OhYa()
    Dim rws As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim f As Range
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

    a = "Accept as Medicare product"
    b = "Accept as NJ Medicaid product"
    c = "Accept as Medicaid product"

    rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & rws)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    For Each f In rng.Cells
        If f <> a And f <> b And f <> c Then
            f.EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        End If
    Next f


End Sub
```