# Is it possible to filter a cell in Excel using several criteria VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if it is possible to filter on a cell in VBA using more than 2 criteria?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$" & NumberOfLines).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*PSO*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*NSM*"...
```

If it's not possible, is there a way to filter a cell using several criteria?

Comment: See previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882661/excel-vba-autofilter-contains-with-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 2):

Using an array, for example, `Criteria1:=Array("2","3", "5")`

Comment: But I have to use the operator or between the criteria. Criteria1 or Criteria2 ... or CriteriaN

Comment: that gives, 2 or 3 or 5