# VBA to Filter a spreadsheet with Criteria values in a array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code for filter criteria based on a array, but it filters exact match and not contains.

I want to filter all contains

I have the code this filters exact match

`Criteria = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A140") & Criteri & :*"` - doesn't work

```
    Sub Filter969696()

Dim Criteria As Variant
Dim cri() As String

Criteria = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A140")

ReDim Preserve cri(UBound(Criteria))

For I = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria)

    cri(I) = Criteria(I, 1)

Next

Worksheets("AP").Range("$A$1:$h$100").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=cri, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Filter all values contains the array provided

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882661/excel-vba-autofilter-contains-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Autofilter contains with multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882661/excel-vba-autofilter-contains-with-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

**Here, Try this code:**

I made it a quite big & Complex though, but it should work.

Too overcome the Excel restriction of 2 **Contains**, i added the exact macthes one by one in a new array and used it to apply the filter at once.

```
Sub Filter969696()

Dim Criteria As Variant
Dim cri() As String
Dim cri2() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Criteria = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A140")

ReDim Preserve cri(UBound(Criteria))
ReDim Preserve cri2(1)

For i = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria)

    cri(i) = "=*" & Criteria(i, 1) & "*"
    Worksheets("AP").Range("$A$1:$h$100").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=cri(i), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    j = UBound(cri2)

    ReDim Preserve cri2(j + Worksheets("AP").Range("$A$1:$h$100").Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count)

        For Each rw In Worksheets("AP").Range("$A$1:$h$100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

                cri2(j + 1) = Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value
                j = j + 1

        Next

Next

Worksheets("AP").Range("$A$1:$h$100").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=cri2, Operator:=xlFilterValues


End Sub
```