# Not showing filters correctly in Excel after AutoFilter VBA code is ran

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a Excel data list with oranges and apples in first 10 rows. Filter is also applied. In excel you can filter them and select oranges or apples, so only selected one is visible, with excel filter. With VBA code:

`ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>orange"`

I'm able to filter out oranges and there are only apples visible(this is applying text filter). But problem is the when I click on the filter none of the items are selected(in the pictures). I need to see items that are not filtered(apples), like when you do it from Excel manually.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="apple"
```

**Instead of:**

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>orange"
```

That Not Equal sign takes it to `TextFilter`.

[You might benefit from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845092/filter-contains-criteria-with-array/56845379#56845379)

Comment: Yes, but this is just a simple example. In real file I have about 30 different categories(plus dates).

Comment: @IGRACH .. An Array would be a Solution. read from the Link I gave in the Answer