# Is there a way to filter on the basis of 10+ criteria within each cell?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have an Excel sheet in which I need to filter the rows on the basis of multiple criteria.

The information is sometimes in the middle of cell.
E.g.,
C12: JFK Jan 2018 Coffee
C13: LGA 01/2018 Pizza
C14: SFA Pasta Mar2017.

I need to filter rows that relate to January 2018 on the basis of as many ways of writing January 2018 as possible for a few hundred rows.

I tried the following:

```vb
Sub myFilter()
    
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim eleData As Variant
    Dim eleCrit As Variant
    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim vTst As Variant
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    vTst = Array("*Jan 2018*", "*JAN 2018*", "*01/2018*", "*012018*", "*12018*")
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        arrData = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Row.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each eleCrit In vTst
            For Each eleData In arrData
                If eleData Like eleCrit Then dic(eleData) = vbNullString
            Next
        Next
        .Columns("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:=dic.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

This code gives

> run time error
> "Object doesn't support this property or method".

I would adjust the code, if it runs on my small sample, to also fit the bigger data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Excel is Restricted to a search for max 2 words with Wildcard, so maybe you are looking for something like this, a work Around for that issue**

```
Sub myFilter()

Dim Crit() As Variant
Dim cri() As String
Dim cri2() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Crit = Array("Jan 2018", "JAN 2018", "01/2018", "012018", "12018")
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row) 'HERE Range

ReDim Preserve cri(UBound(Crit))
ReDim Preserve cri2(1)



For i = LBound(Crit) To UBound(Crit)

    cri(i) = "=*" & Crit(i) & "*"


    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cri(i), Operator:=xlFilterValues 'HERE Field in the Range i.e column Number

    j = UBound(cri2)

    ReDim Preserve cri2(j + rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count)

        For Each rw In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

                cri2(j + 1) = Cells(rw.row, "B").Value 'HERE Column that corresponds to the Filtered Field in this case B
                Debug.Print cri2(j + 1)
                j = j + 1

        Next

Next

rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cri2, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'HERE Again Field to Filter On

End Sub
```

**Note:**

- Don't need to add `*` in the Array, it already does that.
- Taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56845379/5720144)
- If you want to fiddle with the code and change the Range or Field where to Filter, I have Marked 4 places in the code. Change the Variables Accordingly.

---

**Working:**
[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for sharing the code, it worked!!! Sorry I didn't find it myself.=)